# MIDI bulk dump message is sometimes missing bytes or split into two messages after calling MidiInputPort.send()

Tags: android, kotlin, midi

I'm developing a MIDI controller application using the `android.media.midi` package, and part of its functionality is sending bulk dump messages. These are relatively large in size compared to simple note/parameter change messages and I'm having some trouble getting the bulk dump messages to arrive at their destination. (FYI, I'm sending data over a Roland UM-ONE plugged into my phone and monitoring the data being received by my audio/midi interface using [Mountain Utilities MIDI Tools](https://mountainutilities.eu/miditools).) Sending the entire byte array (which is 392 bytes long) in a single call to `MidiInputPort.send()` never worked. Typically only about half of the bytes would arrive. Eventually I ended up making a bunch of consecutive calls to `send()` sending just three bytes of the bulk dump array at a time.

This is where I start to run into some confusing issues. I'll try to explain this as clearly as I can. Sometimes the entire bulk dump is received and everything is good. Other times it gets split into two incomplete messages, one that's 256 bytes long and one that's 134 bytes long. The only two bytes missing in this case are the checksum and end byte. Sometimes it just arrives as one incomplete message that's 240 bytes long. This is the first 240 bytes of the bulk dump, and all the rest is missing. These are always the sizes that they end up being.

Whether or not the entire message is received seems to be dependent on the value of the parameter that was most recently changed in combination with all of the other parameters. When changing a single value in the bulk dump array, it will reliably produce one of the configurations above for certain ranges of that particular parameter. Then when a different parameter is changed, the range that produced a particular configuration for the original parameter no longer applies, and it may produce a complete bulk dump or a different incomplete one.

I verified that the contents of the bulk dump array are what they are expected to be, and that the bytes being sent to the `MidiInputPort` are the same as the ones in the bulk dump array. (No erroneous `0xf7` or `0xf0`s are sneaking in amongst the data). Here is the code I'm using to send the data:

```
val inputPort: MidiInputPort

fun sendBulkDump(data: ByteArray) {
  var bytesSent = 0
  while (bytesSent < data.size) {
    val buffer = ByteArray(min(data.size - bytesSent, 3)) { it ->
      data[bytesSent++]
    }
    inputPort.send(buffer, 0, buffer.size)
  }
}
```

I've tried spacing the calls out using the `timeStamp` parameter of the `send()` method, but that typically scrambles up the data even more. I'm totally stumped and I can't figure out why sometimes the MIDI message arrives intact, and sometimes not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it took me over a month but I finally figured out the solution to my problem. It turns out I was calculating the checksum incorrectly. Just in case anyone (for some insane reason) runs into this problem, here's how I'm calculating the checksum now:

```
// ... Build sysex data array -> sysexData: ByteArray

var dataSum: Int = 0
for (i in DATA_START_INDEX until sysexData.size - 2) {
    dataSum += sysexData[i]
}

var checksum = (128 - (dataSum % 128)) % 128
sysexData[sysexData.size - 2] = checksum.toByte()
```

It turns out in MIDI, the most significant bit of the checksum is ignored, thus the only acceptable values are 0 - 127. I was treating it as a signed byte, hence why sometimes the message would be sent successfully. Any time the checksum happened to be between 0 and 127, no problem. Any time the checksum was negative, the receiving program would just reject the checksum and final byte. The reason it was showing up as two separate messages is I guess because there was some 256-byte buffer along the way that would get read in, expecting a valid conclusion to the sysex to follow after the data bytes. When it got the bad checksum it would just give up and show all the data that came post-buffer as its own message.